# How to create a 1 column tableview of checkboxes in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, checkbox, tableview

What are the correct steps to create a single column tableview with a fixed number of checkboxes.  For example the column could have the following (X indicates the checkbox checked, _ indicates the checkbox unchecked.  I also desire text headings in the same column.):

Heading one:

X item 1

_ item 2

X item 3

X item 4

Heading two:

X item 5

_ item 6

I prefer to do this using Cocoa bindings if possible.  Also I need to know how to get the on/off checked states of any items that the user checks or unchecks. I need to know how to set the title text of the checkboxes to "item 1", "item 2" etc.

What I'm trying to do is use tableview to create a listbox of items with checkboxes like can be done in Microsoft MFC.  Please be explicit in code explanations and describing IB steps as I'm very new to Cocoa and Objective-C.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have made this project for you and recorded in a screencast how I have made it.
Everything is so laggy just because it is too hard to screencast for my old 2008y MacBook

Project: [Download](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7809457/TableView.zip)
Screencast: [Download](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7809457/New.mov)

Comment: I really appreciate the example, but how do I put the labels in the same column as the checkboxes?  I'm also unclear about how in IB dragging a single checkbox into a column, allows one to instantiate a checkbox for each row?

Comment: Never mind on the question about putting the labels in the same column.  I see that they are.  I can reposition the label in a given row, and hide the button in that row. Thanks!

Comment: One question: how and where are the multiple checkboxes and labels being instantiated for each row?  I.e. a checkbox and label is being created for each row, but how?  In the code it seems like you are just accessing the first checkbox and label (and index 0 and 1 respectively)

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing from an iPad, so sorry for any mistakes, I can't test the code
1) in IB put a nstableview, make it 1 column in inspector, make it view based, name the column MainCoumn. Put checkbox in the tableviewcell.
2) select yor table view, open the forth tab in the inspector and connect delegate and datasource with AppDelegate.
3) in your AppDelegate.h add this:

```
<NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource>
```

After : NSObject

4) in your AppDelegate.m add this:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
if( [tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"MainColumn"] )
{
    NSArray *subviews = cellView.subviews;
    NSButton *checkbox = [subviews objectAtIndex:1];
    cellView.textField.stringValue = @"checkbox";
   //  [checkbox state];  - check is it checked
  //   [checkbox setState:0];  - 0 is to set it unchecked, 1- checked. 
    // if you need to make the second one checked, other - unchecked:
   if (row == 1) {
    [checkbox setState:1];
    } else {
     [checkbox setState:0]; 
    }
    return cellView;
}
return cellView;    
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
return 6 
   // here you type the number of rows
}
```

5) profit111

Comment: So what about setting the checkbox of given row's text?  Is that a stringValue?  And what about having the header's (without a checkbox) in the same column (used to identify/separate/group the checkboxes?

Comment: The code is yielding an exception related to the index being out of bounds.

Comment: to change text you have to use .title, not .stringValue